# Conditional parallelism in reactor project

Tags: parallel-processing, spring-webflux, project-reactor

There is a stream in which messages must be parsed parallel based on a specific field.

Using `groupBy` isn't an option, because it collects a chunk of results and then groups them(it introduces delay).
Also, if `subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())` is used, the result is okay, but it introduces a starvation problem.

As an example orders with the same `batchId` should be executed sequentially. Thus, orders 1 and 2 should be processed sequentially, and order 3 can be executed parallel.

```
    record Order(Integer id,Integer batchId){}
    void testParallel() {
        Flux.just(new Order(1,1),new Order(2,1),new Order(3,2));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create 2 separate `Flux` instances. One that process each emitted item sequential and another that process them in parallel. You can then `merge` them into a single `Flux`.

Something along the lines of

```java
        Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
                .collectList()
                .flatMapMany(list -> {
                    Stream<Integer> sequential = list.stream().filter(i -> i < 4);
                    Stream<Integer> parallel = list.stream().filter(i -> i > 3);
                    Flux<Integer> sequentialFlux = Flux.fromStream(sequential).concatMap(i -> /** do your work **/);
                    Flux<Integer> parallelFlux = Flux.fromStream(parallel).flatMap(i -> /** do your work **/);

                    return Flux.merge(sequentialFlux, parallelFlux);
                }).log().subscribe();
```

In the example above, elements `1, 2, 3` will be processed sequentially whereas elements `3, 4, 5` will processed in parallel.

*Note*

You did not make it clear what conditional logic needs to be applied so I have just apply some dummy logic for now.

Also, `collectList()` should only be used with finite streams.

[concatMap docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-) - `this operator waits for one inner to complete before generating the next one and subscribing to it.`

[merge docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-) - `Unlike concat, sources are subscribed to eagerly`

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. A solution is needed to parallelize dynamically in runtime, not a hardcoded solution.

Comment: @MohsenKashi updated to make it more dynamic

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are a bit vague but it seems like `bufferUntilChanged` could do the trick. In your example, it would collect successive elements of one batch and then emit them.

```
flux.bufferUntilChanged(Order::getBatchId)
```

This returns a `Flux<List<Order>>`. You can process the lists in parallel.

`windowUntilChanged` could also be an option. It would return a `Flux<Flux<Order>>`.